# Unable to access file system after Android 9 to 10 change

Tags: android, android-file

I have an app that uses files on the storage device. This has been running absolutely fine on Android 9. One of the things it does is browse a directory to get a list of files.

I have just updated to Android 10. All of a sudden, there are (apparently) no files in the directory. However actually all the same files are there according to Total Commander.

The code (folder being a String set to /storage/emulated/0/uk.co.nightshade-arts/maps) is

```
...
String []
        rawFiles;

try {
    File    f = new File(folder);

    rawFiles = f.list();
}

catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
}

...
```

rawFiles ends up as null, which is what list() should return if the path is not a folder - but it is a folder.

However, (1) the files have not changed, (2) they are definitely there according to Total Commander and (3) another app with the same storage permissions, target API etc, using the same code to list a (different) directory still works absolutely fine.

Can anyone suggest what might have changed between Android 9 and 10 that might cause this?

As an aside I also notice that Android Studio continually disconnects from the target (Google Pixel 2) so debugging fails now the phone runs 10. That didn't used to happen, either.

Comment: If you are targetting Android 10, there have been changes to the storage access framework, via a thing called Scoped Storage, you can look at the changes here and see how they affect the app:: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#scoped-storage

Comment: Thanks, but still actually targeting 9, as is the other app. I'll have a look, though.

Comment: Yes, see below. It was that. Actually this app was targeting API 29 by mistake, not 28, the other was targeting 28. So the other was OK, this wasn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no access to that directory targetting Android Q indeed.

That is what has changed.

No access to getExternalStorageDirectory() anymore.

Add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to manifest if you want to continue in the old way until R.

Comment: I have a horrible feeling you are right. However (1) cannot understand why the other app built with same code and target API has no problem, and (2) when I DO add the above to the manifest. if fails to build due to the attribute being not found. Hey ho. Building Android code reminds me of old style text-based adventure games from the 80's (colossal cave etc) - every time you go round a corner there's a dwarf with an axe waiting to kill you.

Comment: Yes, solved, thanks for your help. Other app was targeting API 28, this one 29. That is the difference. The reason the attribute was missing was probably because this one's compile API was 28, and that was being used because 29 missed out some GPS API by mistake .... however 28 doesn't have the attribute. I hate moving forwards on Android systems, something always seems to get you.